# Writing a python module so it can be uninstalled

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pypi

I'm creating a Python package for PyPi:

```
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='ubuntudesign-asset-mapper',
    version='0.2',
    author='Robin',
    author_email='robin.winslow@canonical.com',
    url='https://github.com/ubuntudesign/asset-mapper',
    packages=[
        'ubuntudesign'
    ],
    description=(
        'A mapping class for using the Ubuntu asset server.'
    ),
    long_description=open('README.rst').read(),
    install_requires=[
        "requests >= 2.0"
    ]
)
```

I've put it [on PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ubuntudesign-asset-mapper) successfully, and I can install it:

```
$ pip install ubuntudesign-asset-mapper
Downloading/unpacking ubuntudesign-asset-mapper
  Downloading ubuntudesign-asset-mapper-0.2.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/home/robin/.virtualenvs/assets-server/build/ubuntudesign-asset-mapper/setup.py) egg_info for package ubuntudesign-asset-mapper

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests>=2.0 in /home/robin/.virtualenvs/assets-server/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from ubuntudesign-asset-mapper)
Installing collected packages: ubuntudesign-asset-mapper
  Running setup.py install for ubuntudesign-asset-mapper

Successfully installed ubuntudesign-asset-mapper
Cleaning up...
$ pip freeze | grep ubuntud
ubuntudesign-asset-mapper==0.2
```

But now it won't let me uninstall it:

```
$ pip uninstall ubuntudesign-asset-mapper
Can't uninstall 'ubuntudesign-asset-mapper'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

I'm sure it's because I haven't written my `setup.py` properly, but I can't find any reference to this problem online, so I don't know what I've done wrong.

Comment: I can't reproduce. I installed and uninstalled your package fine.

Comment: @Ffisegydd curious - maybe it's a virtualenv problem? - I'm trying it within a virtualenv. Let me experiment.

Comment: I installed it on Mac (yeah I would guess it's made for ubuntu but nvm :P) and installed it using Python 2.7 and it worked fine.

Comment: What version of python and pip are you using?

Comment: @BrendanAbel it's version `1.5.6`. Actually, when I try to run `pip freeze` *outside* of a virtualenv, I get an error like this one: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1093. Might be related to my problem, which looks like it might be with my version of `pip`.

Comment: I'm running Python2.7 and pip 1.5.6. Installed and uninstalled without any problems. Have you tried to install and uninstall your package outside of a virtualenv?